# Selecting features in order using python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, select, order

I am building a plugin in QGIS 2.14 that takes a selection of lines and creates one followong the path of those lines already selected.

My issue is that the traditional selection does not respect the order we selected the features.
I saw  one topic talking on this here : [Get features in order they are selected using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70165/get-features-in-order-they-are-selected-using-qgis) but I didn't manage to implement it.
Do you guys have an example of a code using it, as the need is :

1. Select the features from the map
2. Click on the plugin button to peform the operation

Comment: As a start for brainstorming, I was using this code :
    for feat in lyr.selectedFeatures :
        code...

But as I said, the slection does not respect the order of selection.

Comment: I tried it out in QGIS 3 and my adaptation of link's code worked as expected. Please, put your code in your question for possible reopening it.