# Storing printed values at Python Console of QGIS as variable?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Based in this answer to [Getting features in order they are selected using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70165/getting-features-in-order-they-are-selected-using-pyqgis/70169#70169), I ran following code at Python Console of QGIS 3 for getting features id in order they were selected.

```
def onSelectionChanged():
    try:
        id = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0].id()
        print (id)
    except IndexError:
        print ("no feature selected")

iface.activeLayer().selectionChanged.connect( onSelectionChanged )
```

I tried above code out with shapefile visualized at following image, where docked attributes table was used to corroborate that printed values at Python Console had correct order.

[image]

How can I modify my function for storing printed id values at Python Console of QGIS, as a list variable, without using a file written on disk drive?

Comment: If I understand well, you can define a variable out of the function and modify it inside, appending to it each new selected id.

Comment: @Germán Carrillo Thanks for your comment. How can I do that? I tried it out and list was always empty. How can I pass a reference for redirecting values created into function to variable created outside function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me from the QGIS Python console:

```
selected_ids = []
print(selected_ids) # prints []

def onSelectionChanged():
    try:
        id = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0].id()
        selected_ids.append(id)
    except IndexError:
        print ("no feature selected")

iface.activeLayer().selectionChanged.connect( onSelectionChanged )

# Now select some features 

print(selected_ids) # prints [423, 347]
```

Comment: It was so easy. This is the answer. It was also considered by my. However, my issue was that I passed as parameter to the function, the ids list. Thanks a lot.